# Converting A Query with Left Join and Inner Join into Knex

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, knex.js

Can anyone help me with this block to convert into Knex?

```
SELECT d.id, d.title, u.update_id, u."date"
FROM documents d
LEFT JOIN
-- JOIN "documents" against the most recent update per document_id
(
SELECT recent.document_id, id AS update_id, recent."date"
FROM updates
INNER JOIN
(SELECT document_id, MAX("date") AS "date" FROM updates GROUP BY 1) recent
ON updates.document_id = recent.document_id
WHERE
  updates."date" = recent."date"
) u
ON d.id = u.document_id;
```

I grabbed this from:
[PostgreSQL , Select from 2 tables, but only the latest element from table 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703495/postgresql-select-from-2-tables-but-only-the-latest-element-from-table-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
// SELECT d.id, d.title, u.update_id, u."date"
// FROM documents d
knex('documents as d')
  .select('d.id', 'd.title', 'u.update_id', 'u.date')

  //LEFT JOIN
  //-- JOIN "documents" against the most recent update per document_id
  .leftJoin(

    //(
    //SELECT recent.document_id, id AS update_id, recent."date"
    //FROM updates
    knex('updates')
      .select('recent.document_id', 'id AS update_id', 'recent.date')
      
      //INNER JOIN
      //(SELECT document_id, MAX("date") AS "date" FROM updates GROUP BY 1) recent
      //ON updates.document_id = recent.document_id
      //WHERE
      //  updates."date" = recent."date"
      //) u
      .innerJoin(
        knex('updates')
          .select('document_id', knex.raw('MAX(??) AS date', ['date']))
          .groupBy(knex.raw('1'))
          .as('recent'),
        'updates.document_id',
        'recent.document_id'
      )
      .where('updates.date', knex.ref('recent.date'))
      .as('u'),

    // ON d.id = u.document_id;  
    'd.id',
    'u.document_id'
  )
```

https://runkit.com/embed/916cxiubn6h7

```
// without comments
knex('documents as d')
  .select('d.id', 'd.title', 'u.update_id', 'u.date')
  .leftJoin(
    knex('updates')
      .select('recent.document_id', 'id AS update_id', 'recent.date')
      .innerJoin(
        knex('updates')
          .select('document_id', knex.raw('MAX(??) AS date', ['date']))
          .groupBy(knex.raw('1'))
          .as('recent'),
        'updates.document_id',
        'recent.document_id'
      )
      .where('updates.date', knex.ref('recent.date'))
      .as('u'),
    'd.id',
    'u.document_id'
  )
  .toSQL()
```