# POSTGRES JOIN row with latest date from other tables with GROUP BY is slow

Tags: postgresql

So I have this query for my POSTGRES database. You see comments in the query which marks the part which slows down the query. In this "slow" part I want to join 3 tables. But I only want to join the the row which got created the latest (created_at) column. It slows down the query a lot and makes it not useful any more. Is there any chance to speed up the query?

Also `distinct on` is very slow like suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1708832/19165490).

Here is a link to the `explain analyze` of the whole query [file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1No_gcbH_Z0Js1QwB7bFCvne3Kxun0xnWo8eCubS8BaI/edit?usp=sharing).
And the `explain analyze` of the simplified query (stated also in this question) is parsed below.

Thank you for the efforts!

```js
SELECT *
FROM setup s
FULL JOIN
  (SELECT part_type AS f_part_type,
          p_m_id AS f_p_m_id,
          YEAR AS f_year,
                  model_name AS f_model_name,
                  brand_name AS f_brand_name
   FROM part_model) pm ON s.p_m_part_id = pm.f_p_m_id
FULL JOIN
  (SELECT p_id AS p_id_1,
          p_setup_id AS p_setup_id_1,
          part_type AS part_type_1
            FROM part) p ON s.s_id = p.p_setup_id_1
AND p.part_type_1 = 'Fork'
-- starting here query is slowed down
  LEFT JOIN(
                    SELECT recent.* FROM setup_part_setting
                    INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT s_p_s_id as s_p_s_id_1, 
                    part_id as part_id_1,
                    s_setup_id as s_setup_id_1, 
                    MAX("created_at") as created_at_1
                    FROM setup_part_setting sps_inner_1 GROUP BY 1) recent
                    on recent.s_p_s_id_1 = setup_part_setting.s_p_s_id
                    WHERE
                      setup_part_setting.created_at = recent.created_at_1
                    ) u
                    ON s.s_id = u.s_setup_id_1 AND p.p_id_1 = u.part_id_1   
-- until here query is slowed down         
WHERE ((f_brand_name ilike ANY (ARRAY [['%%']])
        AND f_model_name ilike ANY (ARRAY [['%%']])
        AND f_year ilike ANY (ARRAY [['%%']]))
        OR (f_brand_name IS NULL
            OR f_model_name IS NULL
            OR f_year IS NULL))
ORDER BY s.created_at DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

`explain analyze`

Limit  (cost=694.55..694.57 rows=5 width=277) (actual time=206.186..206.191 rows=5 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=694.55..710.39 rows=6334 width=277) (actual time=206.184..206.189 rows=5 loops=1)
Sort Key: s.created_at DESC
Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
->  Hash Left Join  (cost=220.19..589.35 rows=6334 width=277) (actual time=150.088..204.156 rows=6478 loops=1)
Hash Cond: ((s.s_id = sps_inner_1.s_setup_id) AND (part.p_id = sps_inner_1.part_id))
->  Hash Full Join  (cost=209.74..531.38 rows=6334 width=237) (actual time=149.736..201.489 rows=6403 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (s.s_id = part.p_setup_id)
Join Filter: (part.part_type = 'Fork'::text)
Rows Removed by Join Filter: 51
Filter: (((part_model.brand_name ~~* ANY ('{{%%}}'::text[])) AND (part_model.model_name ~~* ANY ('{{%%}}'::text[])) AND (part_model.year ~~* ANY ('{{%%}}'::text[]))) OR (part_model.brand_name IS NULL) OR (part_model.model_name IS NULL) OR (part_model.year IS NULL))
->  Hash Full Join  (cost=205.54..207.00 rows=6335 width=216) (actual time=149.685..151.961 rows=6352 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (s.p_m_part_id = part_model.p_m_id)
->  Seq Scan on setup s  (cost=0.00..1.37 rows=37 width=171) (actual time=0.012..0.022 rows=39 loops=1)
->  Hash  (cost=126.35..126.35 rows=6335 width=45) (actual time=149.643..149.644 rows=6316 loops=1)
Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 568kB
->  Seq Scan on part_model  (cost=0.00..126.35 rows=6335 width=45) (actual time=1.005..147.254 rows=6316 loops=1)
->  Hash  (cost=2.98..2.98 rows=98 width=21) (actual time=0.039..0.040 rows=76 loops=1)
Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB
->  Seq Scan on part  (cost=0.00..2.98 rows=98 width=21) (actual time=0.012..0.026 rows=76 loops=1)
->  Hash  (cost=10.44..10.44 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.331..0.333 rows=191 loops=1)
Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 20kB
->  Hash Join  (cost=6.40..10.44 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.184..0.289 rows=191 loops=1)
Hash Cond: ((setup_part_setting.s_p_s_id = sps_inner_1.s_p_s_id) AND (setup_part_setting.created_at = (max(sps_inner_1.created_at))))
->  Seq Scan on setup_part_setting  (cost=0.00..3.68 rows=68 width=16) (actual time=0.010..0.036 rows=191 loops=1)
->  Hash  (cost=5.38..5.38 rows=68 width=32) (actual time=0.147..0.148 rows=191 loops=1)
Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 20kB
->  HashAggregate  (cost=4.02..4.70 rows=68 width=32) (actual time=0.085..0.114 rows=191 loops=1)
Group Key: sps_inner_1.s_p_s_id
->  Seq Scan on setup_part_setting sps_inner_1  (cost=0.00..3.68 rows=68 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.028 rows=191 loops=1)
Planning time: 42.701 ms
Execution time: 207.047 ms

Comment: You will probably get a better assistance if you boil down your question to the problematic part - the join of the tables `setup_part_setting` and show the `explain analyze` of it. An alternative single query using `row_number`to filter the last row is a possibility. Obviously you will profite while not performing the join 3 times but only once in a CTE.

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? (in plain text) This gives you many details about why the query is slower then expected.

Comment: I was not sure if the problematic part has anything to do with the non problematic part. That is why I parsed the whole query (simplified of course). I added a link to the `explain analyze` file in the question itself.

Comment: I simplified the query and tried to boil down the problem.

Comment: The query and the query plan don't match.

Comment: Sorry, now they match.